# HTML how do I italicize the same word if typed without having to individually type the code?

Tags: html, italics

I am making a guide for one of my games that I play and I want to know if there is a way to italicize specific words that are typed multiple times without having to type `<i>` and `</i>` over and over again. I tried looking up how to but either I'm blind or I can't find how.

Comment: Not with HTML alone. You could use JavaScript to find those words and put them into an `i` element automatically … but without any basic knowledge, this would be to broad to explain here.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me which tutorial it would be? like Js loop or whatever it is?

Answer (score 0):

Must be done with javascript. Here you go...

```js
var wordAr = ["quick", "fox",];
 
var theText = document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML;
 
for (i in wordAr) {
    theText = theText.replace(new RegExp(wordAr[i], 'g'), '<i>'+wordAr[i]+'</i>');
}
 
document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML = theText;
```

```html
<div id="theText">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
```